# Проблема паузы (?)

Tags: java, android

Нужно, что бы автоматически вывелся текст в `TextView`, а по прошествию паузы он изменился.
У меня так:

```
...
tv.setText("1");
SystemClock.sleep(2000);
tv.setText("2");
...
```

Но результат только такой: Пауза и выведение `tv.setText("2");`, а вот 
    `tv.setText("1");` - нет вообще. Менял виды 
    пауз, виды действий до и после неё, виды методов (по клику, по 
    перенаправлению ...), но увы, он будто игнорирует первое действие. Вероятно 
    это связано только с виджетами.

Comment: Судя по использованию класса SystemClock, надо добавить метку android к вопросу.

Comment: Все ответы хороши.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте Handler.

```
...
tv.setText("1");
runWithDelay();
...

private void runWithDelay() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("2");
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Comment: Способ работает, View чудесно обновляется, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

`SystemClock.sleep()` не рекомендуется использовать в основном потоке.

Как вариант использовать:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override 
         public void run() { 
              // что-то
         } 
    }, 2000);
```

или

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // тик
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // на финише
    }

}.start();
```

Comment: Да, теперь TextView обновляется. Очень интересный способ CountDownTimer, никогда не видел, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Не надо усыплять главный поток - он из-за этого и не может обновить текст.
Можно сделать через `Handler` или так (у каждой `View` есть свой) :

```
tv.setText("1");
tv.postDelayed(() -> tv.setText("2"), 2000);
```

Comment: Без подсказки никогда бы не догадался, теперь всё работает, спасибо! Единственное, я не понял " у каждой View есть свой"  свой Handler?

Comment: Если точнее, то ссылка на `Handler`, которому они делегируют вызовы своих методов `post...`